# Wrote My own data structure. Mixture of a doubly linked list & unordered map C++

Tags: c++, performance

I decided to make my own data structure. I did this because I wanted a data structure that is a queue but has o(1) time on lookup.

```
    template <class Object>
class ObjectQueue;
template <class Object>
class ObjectQueueNode: private NonCopyable
{
    friend class ObjectQueue<Object>;
public:
    ObjectQueueNode(const glm::ivec3& position)
        : position(position),
        previous(nullptr),
        next(nullptr)
    {}
    ObjectQueueNode(ObjectQueueNode&& orig) noexcept
        : position(orig.position),
        previous(orig.previous),
        next(orig.next)
    {
        orig.previous = nullptr;
        orig.next = nullptr;
    }
    ObjectQueueNode& operator=(ObjectQueueNode&& orig) noexcept
    {
        position = orig.position;
        previous = orig.previous;
        next = orig.next;

        orig.previous = nullptr;
        orig.next = nullptr;

        return *this;
    }

    const glm::ivec3& getPosition() const
    {
        return position;
    }

private:
    glm::ivec3 position;
    Object* previous;
    Object* next;
};

struct PositionNode : public ObjectQueueNode<PositionNode>
{
    PositionNode(const glm::ivec3& position)
        : ObjectQueueNode(position)
    {}
};

template <class Object>
class ObjectQueue : private NonCopyable, private NonMovable
{
public:
    ObjectQueue()
        : m_initialObjectAdded(nullptr),
        m_recentObjectAdded(nullptr),
        m_container()
    {}

    void add(Object&& newObject)
    {
        glm::ivec3 position = newObject.position;
        if (m_container.empty())
        {
            assert(!m_initialObjectAdded && !m_recentObjectAdded);
            Object& addedObject = m_container.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
                std::forward_as_tuple(position),
                std::forward_as_tuple(std::move(newObject))).first->second;

            addedObject.previous = nullptr;
            m_initialObjectAdded = &addedObject;
            m_recentObjectAdded = &addedObject;
        }
        else if (m_container.size() == 1)
        {
            assert(m_initialObjectAdded && m_recentObjectAdded);
            Object& addedObject = m_container.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
                std::forward_as_tuple(position),
                std::forward_as_tuple(std::move(newObject))).first->second;

            addedObject.previous = m_initialObjectAdded;
            m_initialObjectAdded->next = &addedObject;
            m_recentObjectAdded = &addedObject;
        }
        else if (m_container.size() > 1)
        {
            assert(m_initialObjectAdded && m_recentObjectAdded);
            Object& addedObject = m_container.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
                std::forward_as_tuple(position),
                std::forward_as_tuple(std::move(newObject))).first->second;

            addedObject.previous = m_recentObjectAdded;
            m_recentObjectAdded->next = &addedObject;
            m_recentObjectAdded = &addedObject;
        }
    }

    bool contains(const glm::ivec3& position) const
    {
        return m_container.find(position) != m_container.cend();
    }

    bool isEmpty() const
    {
        return m_container.empty();
    }

    Object* next(Object* object)
    {
        assert(m_initialObjectAdded && m_recentObjectAdded && !m_container.empty());
        if (object)
        {
            return object->next;
        }
        else
        {
            return nullptr;
        }
    }

    Object& front()
    {
        assert(m_initialObjectAdded && m_recentObjectAdded && !m_container.empty());

        auto iter = m_container.find(m_initialObjectAdded->position);

        assert(iter != m_container.end());
        return iter->second;
    }

    void pop()
    {
        assert(m_initialObjectAdded && m_recentObjectAdded && !m_container.empty());

        auto iter = m_container.find(m_initialObjectAdded->position);
        assert(iter != m_container.end());

        if (m_container.size() == 1)
        {
            assert(m_initialObjectAdded == m_recentObjectAdded);
            m_initialObjectAdded = nullptr;
            m_recentObjectAdded = nullptr;

        }
        else if (m_container.size() > 1)
        {
            assert(m_initialObjectAdded->next);
            m_initialObjectAdded = m_initialObjectAdded->next;
            m_initialObjectAdded->previous = nullptr;
        }

        m_container.erase(iter);
    }

    Object* remove(const glm::ivec3& position)
    {
        auto iter = m_container.find(position);
        if (iter != m_container.end())
        {
            assert(m_initialObjectAdded && m_recentObjectAdded);
            Object* previousObject = iter->second.previous;
            Object* nextObject = iter->second.next;

            //Top
            if (!nextObject && previousObject)
            {
                m_recentObjectAdded = previousObject;
                m_recentObjectAdded->next = nullptr;
                previousObject->next = nullptr;
            }
            //Bottom
            else if (!previousObject && nextObject)
            {
                m_initialObjectAdded = nextObject;
                m_initialObjectAdded->previous = nullptr;
                nextObject->previous = nullptr;
            }
            //Inbetween
            else if (previousObject && nextObject)
            {
                previousObject->next = nextObject;
                nextObject->previous = previousObject;
            }
            else
            {
                assert(m_container.size() == 1);
                m_initialObjectAdded = nullptr;
                m_recentObjectAdded = nullptr;
            }

            m_container.erase(iter);
            return nextObject;
        }

        return nullptr;
    }

private:
    Object* m_initialObjectAdded;
    Object* m_recentObjectAdded;

    std::unordered_map<glm::ivec3, Object> m_container;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Question

Why not just use existing containers so you don't need to manage anything.

```
class ObjectQueue
{
    private:
        std::unordered_map<K, V>   container;    // container to hold object
        std::list<V*>              list;         // list to make your queue?
};
```

### Limiting Observation

Your `Object` type can't be any object. It has to have a member `position` that acts as the key in the container. The type of this key has to be `glm::ivec3`which is a bit limiting.

```
glm::ivec3 position = newObject.position;
```

Normally we would allow the container to specialize the key or provide an access function to get the key.

```
template<typename V, typename K = typename V::Key, typename F = std::function<K(V const&)>>
class MyContainer
{
      // In Here
      // V is the object you are storing
      // K is the key type used.
      //       By default this is defined in V as V::Key
      //       But can be overridden if the V type does not have a Key type.
      // F Is the type of the function that is used to retrieve the Key
      //       from an object of type V.
      //

      // Now we provide a constructor
      // That sets up the key getter method.
      // We can default it to return the position member of object.
      MyContainer(F&& keyGetter = [](V const& o){return o.position})
          : kyeGetter(std::move(keyGetter))
      {}

      bool insert(V&& object) {
          K    key    = keyGetter(object);
          auto insert = m_container.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
                                            std::forward_as_tuple(std::move(key)),
                                            std::forward_as_tuple(std::move(newObject)));

          if (insert.first) { // otherwise it was not inserted.
                              // You may want it in your list twice
                              // But you have to remember that a container item
                              // may have more than one entry in the list.
             m_list.emplace_back(&insert.second);
          }
          return insert.first;
     }

};
```

### Some Code Review

Your move operations are acting more like a copy:

```
ObjectQueueNode(ObjectQueueNode&& orig) noexcept
    : position(orig.position),        // This is a copy
    previous(orig.previous),          // This is a copy (but a pointer so don't care)
    next(orig.next)                   // This is a copy (but a pointer)
{
    orig.previous = nullptr;
    orig.next = nullptr;
}
ObjectQueueNode& operator=(ObjectQueueNode&& orig) noexcept
{
    position = orig.position;        // This is a copy. Add std::move
    previous = orig.previous;
    next = orig.next;

    orig.previous = nullptr;
    orig.next = nullptr;

    return *this;
}
```

The more standard implementation is:

```
ObjectQueueNode(ObjectQueueNode&& orig) noexcept
    : previous(nullptr)
    , next(nullptr)
{
    swap(orig);
}
ObjectQueueNode& operator=(ObjectQueueNode&& orig) noexcept
{
    swap(orig);

    orig.previous = nullptr;
    orig.next     = nullptr;

    return *this;
}
```

---

This is a long windid:

```
struct PositionNode : public ObjectQueueNode<PositionNode>
{
    PositionNode(const glm::ivec3& position)
        : ObjectQueueNode(position)
    {}
};
```

Can be simplified to:

```
using PositionNode = ObjectQueueNode<PositionNode>;
```

---

These two conditions are the same:

```
    else if (m_container.size() == 1)
    {
        assert(m_initialObjectAdded && m_recentObjectAdded);
        Object& addedObject = m_container.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
            std::forward_as_tuple(position),
            std::forward_as_tuple(std::move(newObject))).first->second;

        addedObject.previous = m_initialObjectAdded;
        m_initialObjectAdded->next = &addedObject;
        m_recentObjectAdded = &addedObject;
    }
    else if (m_container.size() > 1)
    {
        assert(m_initialObjectAdded && m_recentObjectAdded);
        Object& addedObject = m_container.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
            std::forward_as_tuple(position),
            std::forward_as_tuple(std::move(newObject))).first->second;

        addedObject.previous = m_recentObjectAdded;
        m_recentObjectAdded->next = &addedObject;
        m_recentObjectAdded = &addedObject;
    }
```